# Чтение из COM порта С++

Tags: c++, c, qt, winapi, com-порт

Есть такой код:

```
HANDLE port = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\COM5", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0,
                                OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

        unsigned char dst[1024];

        unsigned long size = sizeof(dst);
        unsigned long recv;


            COMMTIMEOUTS CommTimeOuts;
            CommTimeOuts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 5;
            CommTimeOuts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
            CommTimeOuts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 0;
            CommTimeOuts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
            CommTimeOuts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 0;

        if(SetCommTimeouts(port, &CommTimeOuts) == 0)
        {
             qDebug() << ("Error of SetCommTimeouts");
        }

        if(port!= INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
                int i;
                for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    if(ReadFile(port,dst,size, &recv,0))
                    {
                        if(recv > 0)
                        {
                            qDebug() << (recv);
                            qDebug() << (dst);
                        }
                    }
                }
                CloseHandle(port);
        }
        else
        {
            qDebug() << ("Error of Handler - INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE");
        }
```

Количество считанный байтов в зависимости от передаваемых данных меняется, но вот в `dst` ничего не записывается, почему?

Comment: dst - просто неизменяемый адрес, типо 0x28ba54, а recv - размер данный, 3, 13, 17, зависит от размера передаваемой строки

Comment: Если с компорта приходит число 3, а не символ '3', то  логично, что Вы ничего "не увидите".

Comment: Почему вы считаете, что в dst ничего не записывается?

Comment: qDebug() << (dst); выводит одно и тоже, в то время, как qDebug() << (recv); выводит разные значения

Comment: вау, что - то я затупил, спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Напишите `QString::fromStdString(qDebug() << std::string((char*)dst, recv));` чтобы выводить полученную строку.